# userAgent is undefined inside _app.tsx while using getInitialProps?

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js, typeerror, server-side

I am getting **userAgent** as `undefined` in the following line of code:-

```
const userAgent = context.req?.headers['user-agent'] ?? '';
```

I am getting **isMobile** as `undefined` also as shown below

[image]

I want to detect the device whether it's a mobile or desktop in the server side.

Currently I am using **Next.js** with **Typescript**.

Here is my full source code:-

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialPageProps(
  (store) =>
    async (context: any): Promise<any> => {
      const userAgent = context.req?.headers['user-agent'] ?? '';
      const { isMobile } = getSelectorsByUserAgent(userAgent);
      store.dispatch(setDevice(isMobile));
      const initialProps = await App.getInitialProps(context);
      return { ...initialProps, userAgent, isMobile };
    }
);

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Here is the simple version of the above code and it also returning **userAgent** as undefined

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ req }: NextPageContext) => {
  const userAgent = req
    ? req.headers['user-agent'] || ''
    : typeof window !== 'undefined'
    ? window.navigator.userAgent
    : '';
  return { userAgent };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working answer :-

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }: AppContext) => {
  const userAgent = ctx.req?.headers['user-agent'] ?? '';
  const isMobile = NextUserAgent.useUserAgent(userAgent).isMobile;
  return { isMobile };
};
```